# update trigger statement

Tags: sql-server-2005

how to use the below query with in a trigger which is automatically fire when self_id column is filled with next record????

```
UPDATE  tree_str
SET     L1_Left = ml.self_id,
    L1_Centre = mc.self_id,
    L1_Right = mr.self_id
FROM    tree_str t LEFT JOIN
    member ml   ON  t.self_id = ml.parent_id
                AND ml.position = 'LEFT' LEFT JOIN
    member mc   ON  t.self_id = mc.parent_id
                AND mc.position = 'CENTER' LEFT JOIN
    member mr   ON  t.self_id = mr.parent_id
                AND mr.position = 'RIGHT'
```

i use the below trigger but its not working.......

```
CREATE TRIGGER autoupdate ON [dbo].[tree_str]
FOR UPDATE
AS BEGIN

UPDATE  tree_str
SET     L1_Left = ml.self_id,
    L1_Centre = mc.self_id,
    L1_Right = mr.self_id
FROM    tree_str t LEFT JOIN
    member ml   ON  t.self_id = ml.parent_id
                AND ml.position = 'LEFT' LEFT JOIN
    member mc   ON  t.self_id = mc.parent_id
                AND mc.position = 'CENTER' LEFT JOIN
    member mr   ON  t.self_id = mr.parent_id
                AND mr.position = 'RIGHT'
END
```

Comment: Please at least try writing the trigger yourself....

Answer (score 0):

Please try below syntax for the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER autoupdate ON dbo.tree_str
AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE  tree_str
    SET L1_Left = ml.self_id, L1_Centre = mc.self_id,  L1_Right = mr.self_id
    FROM tree_str t LEFT JOIN
    member ml   ON  t.self_id = ml.parent_id AND ml.position = 'LEFT' 
    LEFT JOIN member mc   ON  t.self_id = mc.parent_id AND mc.position = 'CENTER' 
    LEFT JOIN member mr   ON  t.self_id = mr.parent_id
    AND mr.position = 'RIGHT'

END
```

One noticeable change is, 'AFTER UPDATE' instead of your 'FOR UPDATE'.